Prove that $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1}^3\sqrt{ \sum\limits_{j=1}^3a_{ji}^2}\leq\sqrt{2}f(a_{11},\cdots,a_{33})$
For a $3\times3$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$, let \begin{aligned}&f(a_{11},a_{21},a_{31},a_{12},a_{22},a_{32},a_{13},a_{23},a_{33})\\=&\text{max}\{|a_{11}+a_{21}+a_{31}|+|a_{12}+a_{22}+a_{32}|+|a_{13}+a_{23}+a_{33}|,\\&|a_{11}+a_{21}-a_{31}|+|a_{12}+a_{22}-a_{32}|+|a_{13}+a_{23}-a_{33}|,\\&|a_{11}-a_{21}+a_{31}|+|a_{12}-a_{22}+a_{32}|+|a_{13}-a_{23}+a_{33}|,\\&|a_{11}-a_{21}-a_{31}|+|a_{12}-a_{22}-a_{32}|+|a_{13}-a_{23}-a_{33}|\},\end{aligned} prove that $$\sqrt{a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{31}^2}+\sqrt{a_{12}^2+a_{22}^2+a_{32}^2}+\sqrt{a_{13}^2+a_{23}^2+a_{33}^2}-\sqrt{2}f(a_{11},a_{21},a_{31},a_{12},a_{22},a_{32},a_{13},a_{23},a_{33})\leq0$$ for all reals $a_{11},a_{21},a_{31},a_{12},a_{22},a_{32},a_{13},a_{23},a_{33}$.
My attempt I can only prove $$\sqrt{a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{31}^2}+\sqrt{a_{12}^2+a_{22}^2+a_{32}^2}+\sqrt{a_{13}^2+a_{23}^2+a_{33}^2}-\sqrt{3}f(a_{11},a_{21},a_{31},a_{12},a_{22},a_{32},a_{13},a_{23},a_{33})\leq0.$$
Proof First we have \begin{aligned}&\sqrt{a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{31}^2}+\sqrt{a_{12}^2+a_{22}^2+a_{32}^2}+\sqrt{a_{13}^2+a_{23}^2+a_{33}^2}\\\leq&\sqrt{3}(\text{max}\{|a_{11}|,|a_{21}|,|a_{31}|\}+\text{max}\{|a_{12}|,|a_{22}|,|a_{32}|\}+\text{max}\{|a_{13}|,|a_{23}|,|a_{33}|\}).\end{aligned} Let $|a_{11}|=\text{max}\{|a_{11}|,|a_{21}|,|a_{31}|\}$, $|a_{12}|=\text{max}\{|a_{12}|,|a_{22}|,|a_{32}|\}$, $|a_{13}|=\text{max}\{|a_{13}|,|a_{23}|,|a_{33}|\}$, then we have \begin{aligned}&f(a_{11},a_{21},a_{31},a_{12},a_{22},a_{32},a_{13},a_{23},a_{33})\\\geq&\frac{1}{2}(|a_{11}+a_{21}+a_{31}|+|a_{12}+a_{22}+a_{32}|+|a_{13}+a_{23}+a_{33}|+|a_{11}-a_{21}-a_{31}|+|a_{12}-a_{22}-a_{32}|+|a_{13}-a_{23}-a_{33}|)\\\geq&\frac{1}{2}(|a_{11}+a_{21}+a_{31}+a_{11}-a_{21}-a_{31}|+|a_{12}+a_{22}+a_{32}+a_{12}-a_{22}-a_{32}|+|a_{13}+a_{23}+a_{33}+a_{13}-a_{23}-a_{33}|)\\=&|a_{11}|+|a_{12}|+|a_{13}|\\=&\text{max}\{|a_{11}|,|a_{21}|,|a_{31}|\}+\text{max}\{|a_{12}|,|a_{22}|,|a_{32}|\}+\text{max}\{|a_{13}|,|a_{23}|,|a_{33}|\},\end{aligned} and therefore we have $$\sqrt{a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{31}^2}+\sqrt{a_{12}^2+a_{22}^2+a_{32}^2}+\sqrt{a_{13}^2+a_{23}^2+a_{33}^2}-\sqrt{3}f(a_{11},a_{21},a_{31},a_{12},a_{22},a_{32},a_{13},a_{23},a_{33})\leq0.$$ However, I can do nothing with the coefficient $\sqrt{2}$, and what I've only known so far is that when $$\sqrt{a_{11}^2+a_{21}^2+a_{31}^2}+\sqrt{a_{12}^2+a_{22}^2+a_{32}^2}+\sqrt{a_{13}^2+a_{23}^2+a_{33}^2}-\sqrt{2}f(a_{11},a_{21},a_{31},a_{12},a_{22},a_{32},a_{13},a_{23},a_{33})=0,$$ the solution takes the form of $a_{11}=x+y,a_{12}=x,a_{13}=y,a_{21}=x+y,a_{22}=-x,a_{23}=-y,a_{31}=a_{32}=a_{33}=0$ where $x,y>0$ and its permutations. Any help will be appreciated.
